# Help using BioPython's IC_Chain functionality for getting protein 3D coordinates from torsion angles

Tags: python, proteins, protein-structure, biopython

I have been successfully using BioPython's functionality for extracting protein torsion angles using the `IC_Chain` module. However, I am currently looking to use the inverse functionality as follows:

```
from Bio.PDB import PDBParser, internal_coords

# Read PDB entry.
parser = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=1, QUIET=1)
structure = parser.get_structure('', 'example.pdb')

# Generate protein internal coordinates (angles).
ic_chain_bound = internal_coords.IC_Chain(structure)
ic_chain_bound.atom_to_internal_coordinates()

# Generate back 3D coordinates from angles.
ic_chain_bound.internal_to_atom_coordinates()
```

but this fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_biopython_internal_coords.py", line 97, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "test_biopython_internal_coords.py", line 89, in main
    ic_chain_bound.internal_to_atom_coordinates()
  File "/software/anaconda/installation/envs/alphafold/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/internal_coords.py", line 661, in internal_to_atom_coordinates
    verbose=verbose, start=start, fin=fin
  File "software/anaconda/installation/envs/alphafold/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/internal_coords.py", line 415, in assemble_residues
    Dict[AtomKey, numpy.array], ric.assemble(verbose=verbose)
  File "/software/anaconda/installation/envs/alphafold/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/internal_coords.py", line 1732, in assemble
    atomCoords = self.get_startpos()
  File "/software/anaconda/installation/envs/alphafold/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Bio/PDB/internal_coords.py", line 1632, in get_startpos
    sp = self.residue.parent.internal_coord.initNCaC.get(self.rbase, None)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'initNCaC'
```

Is this not the intended use? Could someone help me figure out why this is failing?

I'm using [this PDB file](https://pastebin.com/m3P8f8rM) in my example, but the code previously failed for all other PDB files I tried.

Thanks!

Comment: Your `ic_chain_bound.residue.parent.internal_coord` is None... So your `ic_chain_bound.residue.parent` needs to be given coordinates... `help` and `dir` on it may help

Comment: @MatteoFerla set_residues() ---> set_residue() ??? or something else ? trying to figure out from https://biopython.org/docs/latest/api/Bio.PDB.internal_coords.html but I am lost

Comment: here https://biopython.org/docs/dev/api/Bio.PDB.internal_coords.html seems better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that in order to generate the internal coordinates for a protein structure, one shouldn't manually create an `IC_Chain` object, but rather just use the `atom_to_internal_coordinates()` method of the structure and the `internal_to_atom_coordinates()` one for the inverse functionality.

```
structure.atom_to_internal_coordinates()

# Now you have access to the bond angles and lengths
# of the first chain of structure as follows:
chain = list(structure.get_chains())[0]
ic_chain = chain.internal_coord

# Dictionary mapping 3 AtomKeys to a Hedron 
# (with len12, len23, angle fields):
# ic_chain.hedra

# Dictionary mapping 4 AtomKeys to a Dihedraon
# (with angle field for torsion angles):
# ic_chain.dihedra

structure.internal_to_atom_coordinates()
```

Comment: Maybe you know the answer to [this related (and bountied) question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/19570/read-pdb-file-extract-dihedral-angles-modify-dihedral-angles-reconstruct-cart/)?

Answer (score 2):

not able to grasp the question, tried to figure out a way to show the internal_coordinates:

```
from Bio.PDB import PDBParser, PICIO, PDBIO


# Read PDB entry.
parser = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=1, QUIET=1)
structure = parser.get_structure('', 'example.pdb')

print(dir(structure)) # 'atom_to_internal_coordinates' and
                      # 'internal_to_atom_coordinates' seems
                      # to be structure methods


# Generate protein internal coordinates (angles).

structure.atom_to_internal_coordinates(verbose = True)

PICIO.write_PIC(structure[0]['A'], 'internal')


# Generate back 3D coordinates from angles.


pippo = PICIO.read_PIC('internal')

pippo.internal_to_atom_coordinates(verbose = True)

print(pippo)


io = PDBIO()

io.set_structure(pippo)

io.save('atom_coord.pdb',  preserve_atom_numbering=True)
```

compare `example.pdb` to `internal` and `atom_coord.pdb`;

have a look at `internal`  file contents if you comment out

`structure.atom_to_internal_coordinates(verbose = True)` (around line 17 of

code, # Generate protein internal coordinates (angles). block-code )